# scraping page links using selenium always return limited number of links

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all matches links from this page 'https://m.aiscore.com/basketball/20210610' but can get only limiter numberof matches:
I tried this code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/chromedriver.exe", options=options)

url = 'https://m.aiscore.com/basketball/20210610'
driver.get(url)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(60) 

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")    

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

links = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('.w100.flex a')]
links_length = len(links) #always return 16
driver.quit()
```

When I run the code, I get always 16 matches links only, but the page has 35 matches.
I need to get allthe matches links in the page.

Comment: Your code in my ubuntu machine works perfectly (I only changed the chrome executable path). What version of chromedriver are you using?

Comment: i use version 91

Comment: do you want me to give you the code to get all the links on that page?

Answer (score 6):

As the site is being loaded when scrolled, I have tried to Scroll one screen at a time until the height we need to scroll to is larger than the total scroll height of the window.

I have used a `set` for storing the match links to avoid adding already existing match links.

At the time of running this, I was able to find all the links. Hope this will work for you as well.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\chromedriver.exe", options=options)

url = 'https://m.aiscore.com/basketball/20210610'
driver.get(url)
# Wait till the webpage is loaded
time.sleep(2)

# wait for 1sec after scrolling
scroll_wait = 1

# Gets the screen height
screen_height = driver.execute_script("return window.screen.height;")
driver.implicitly_wait(60) 

# Number of scrolls. Initially 1
ScrollNumber = 1

# Set to store all the match links
ans = set()

while True:
    # Scrolling one screen at a time until
    driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {screen_height * ScrollNumber})")
    ScrollNumber += 1
    
    # Wait for some time after scroll
    time.sleep(scroll_wait)
    
    # Updating the scroll_height after each scroll
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight;")
    
    # Fetching the data that we need - Links to Matches
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    for j in soup.select('.w100 .flex a'):
        if j['href'] not in ans:
            ans.add(j['href'])
    # Break when the height we need to scroll to is larger than the scroll height
    if (screen_height) * ScrollNumber > scroll_height:
        break
    
    
print(f'Links found: {len(ans)}')
```

```
Output:

Links found: 61
```

Comment: return Links found: 0, the driver didn't open the website (Server error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.)

Comment: @khaled koubaa There's a Server error. Even I'm getting server error using a browser. May be the URL (https://m.aiscore.com/basketball/20210610) isn't valid anymore. You can check with some other URL.

Comment: @khaledkoubaa I have checked my code with this URL (https://m.aiscore.com/basketball) and I am getting all the links from it.

Comment: @khaledkoubaa Did you look at my previous comment ?

Comment: I need to scrape specific dates not just https://m.aiscore.com/basketball

Comment: @khaledkoubaa Did you mention that in your question ?

Comment: yes, check the the url in the code, it's url = 'https://m.aiscore.com/basketball/20210610'

Comment: @khaledkoubaa I have already mentioned that the URL isn't valid anymore. Please read our above discussions.

Comment: I ttied other other url with other close dates and same, only 'https://m.aiscore.com/basketball' work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233999/discussion-between-ram-and-khaled-koubaa).

Answer (score 2):

You're not adding any implicated waits into your code. You might want to start there. But try using `driver.find_elements_by_link_text()` in addition to adding some sleep time, that should create a list for you.